# Как сделать уведомление «неверный пароль..»

Tags: php, html, css

Как мне сделать уведомление «неверный пароль» над моими input? Я знаю, что это делается через echo “и тут html”; но оно мне выводит в левом верхнем углу, а мне надо над input

Comment: Так и выводить надо рядом с инпутом, не?

Comment: То есть там где проверка пароля , это нужно писать там где и хочу вывести. Просто я писал всегда сверху php, а потом html

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.input-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.input-wrap .error {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 135px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 10;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.input-wrap .error::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrap">
  <div class="error">Неверный пароль</div>
  <input type="password" value="12345">
</div>
```